# How to restore edittext data i lost accidentally?

Tags: android

I have accidentally closed my app and i lost data in `editext` after I open it. If it is small login page with username and password it is fine. But when it comes to registration page with all address information filled in it and lost after i open it is really annoying. How to solve this issues?

Thank you

Comment: You should save the data in Shared preferences. For more info see here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Use the room database if you want to support the form data or in a multiple screen. Share preference would be good to save tokens or minimal data.

Comment: @Rohit Padma how does room database helpful in this situation.

Comment: @Robo250 You can save the form data in tables on the close of the activity in onDestroy method. I was suggesting this only if you want to maintain or save a lot of of data in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for saved state?

You implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods, like:

```
public override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    // store variables
    savedInstanceState.putInt("yourInt", 123)
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("yourBool", true)
    savedInstanceState.putString("yourString", "Hello")
}

public override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    val yourInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("yourInt")
    val yourBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("yourBool")
    val yourString = savedInstanceState.getString("yourString")
    // use variables ...
}
```

Note that this will save your form data if you accidentally close the app, but not when you click the back button and close the app normally.

If you want to implement save form data as draft, then you have to handle back button and store data in either Room or shared preferences.

Comment: Please quote and highlight the most important parts of the link. It is probable that the link becomes unavailable in the future.

Comment: How does saveinstance will be helpful for my situation, i mean how can implement with edittext

Comment: @Robo250 I added another answer, there was code in it so it didn't fit in a comment

Answer (score 0):

did you try this code:

```
public override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    savedInstanceState.putString("yourEdittext", edittext.text)
}

public override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    edittext.text = savedInstanceState.getString("yourEdittext")
}
```

press Home on your device (not Back) and then run:

`$ adb shell am kill com.packagename.appname`

without the above code, text will not be restored

now, as I said before, if you are looking for save draft feature, it's quite different, you have to handle back key and show a confirmation dialog, then store it in Room or somewhere.